# What happens when the integrating factor is a factor of neither x or y?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got a differential equation $2\sin(\omega y)dx+\omega\cos(\omega y)dy=0$

They are not exact equations so I need an integrating factor to make them so. I am loosely following this website as a guide; http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html (I say loosely as it is the closest to my lecturer's notes)

And I am using the method of getting the integrating factor;

$(dM/dy - dN/dx)/N$

I get an integrating factor of 2. Is this correct? Would this give me the right answer once I solve the DE?

When is it appropriate to use $(dM/dy - dN/dx)/N$ instead of $(dN/dx - dM/dy)/M$?

(Sorry, I can't get division to work in MathJAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you variables are separated, so it is not a big problem.

Rewrite the equation as  $x(y)' = - \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{\frac{d \sin \omega y}{dy}}{\sin \omega y}$ or $x = x_0 -\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sin(\omega y))$

If you want the more general case you need to look at total differential [site here](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/integrating-totalexact-differentials.html) and especially the Schwarz conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\frac{dx}{dy} + \frac{w\cos wy}{2\sin wy}=0$$so the integrating factor is $$e^{\int \frac{w\cos wy}{2\sin wy}}=e^{\frac12\ln(\sin wy)} = (\sin wy)^{\frac12}$$Indeed $$(\sin wy)^\frac12\ \frac{dx}{dy} + \frac w 2\cos wy (\sin wy)^{-\frac12}  = \frac{d}{dy}\left(x(\sin wy)^\frac12\right)$$